# PHP remove/fix module not found or already loaded warnings?

Tags: php, php-ini

When i run a php script from the command line like below

```
php test.php
```

i get following output

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

how do i fix or remove these module warnings ? I checked the php.ini in

```
etc/php.ini
```

output of

```
php -i | grep php.ini
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

i dont see any loading or any reference to these two modules in there ...

please help

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://www.somacon.com/p520.php ? Also my php.ini for command line is located in  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini . Maybe you have also an other configuration somewhere else

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same situation. In my case the problem was that I had two configuration files for memcache in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/.

```
php -i | grep memcache.ini
```

In my case the result was:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-memcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcache.ini
```

To get rid of the warning message I removed the line `extension=memcache.so` from the memcache.ini file.

Answer (score 16):

When you install php5-memcache it adds it's own memcache.ini file which is set to load that extension already. So Just remove/comment the loading of the extension from your php.ini.

```
 ;extension=memcache.so
```

Similar with APC (Alternative PHP Cache Module).

```
 ;extension=apc.so
```

Comment: as i said in my question, i dont have that line in my php.ini so where shodul i look to ?

Comment: You probably looking @ wrong php.ini. Have you tried php -i | grep php.ini ?

Comment: no there is only one and only php.ini file, output for yoru command is 

PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini

Comment: @mahen3d , it is probably loaded in from another, ini file dedicated to memcache, so check something like


    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcache.ini

Answer (score 5):

If you are using php5.4 (CentOS 6.5),

- Goto `/etc/php.d/`
- in `memcache.ini` comment the extension

  ```
  ;extension=memcache.so
  ```
- likewise in `apc.ini`

  ```
  ;extension=apc.so
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a solution to a similar error i.e. `Warning: Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`.
After looking at various sites, here's the solution I came up with. 
It worked for me, hope it does for someone with a similar issue.

- Locate the **folder** `conf.d`, mine was in the directory
  `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d`.
- In this folder, there's a **file** called `ext-pdo_pgsql.ini`.
- Type `sudo nano ext-pdo_pgsql.ini` to edit it.
- There should be a line `extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so"`. Comment it
  out by adding semi-colon to the beginning of the line i.e.
  `;extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so"`.
- Save the file. (I usually run **control + O**, **control + M**).
- Exit the file (**control + X**).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that these modules are listed twice and so you get error "Already loaded". 
Find out which configuration files are loaded

```
php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
php -i | grep 'ini'
```

This will tell you which .ini files are loaded and parsed (Additional .ini files parsed).

Look at the specific files and comment out the second occurrence (as follows)

```
;extension=memcache.so
;extension=apc.so
```

Answer (score 0):

there are configuration files modules **/etc/php5/mods-available**

Open file pdo_mysql.ini and **comment** line **pdo_mysql.so**

After **service apache2 | php5-fpm restart** depending on whether you are using you

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error,

```
Module 'sphinx' already loaded
```

You need to find module (.ini) which is getting loaded more than once and delete one of them,

```
ubuntu@webserver:~$ grep -R "sphinx" /etc/php5/*

/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/sphinx.ini:extension=sphinx.so
/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-sphinx.ini:extension=sphinx.so

ubuntu@webserver:~$ sudo rm /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/sphinx.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

if you dont whants to update in config file,
just add on top of your page or constructor "**error_reporting(0)**"