# Codeigniter Version 3.0.6 Showing Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have installed `Codeigniter Version 3.0.6` successfully but its showing me an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: Module 'zip' already loaded

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can refer on this article i guess http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653926/php-remove-fix-module-not-found-or-already-loaded-warnings

Answer (score 0):

this error is because in the application/config/autoload.php are loading the module zip, and if you don´t have it installed in your server you need to install, or quit it from autoload.php