# Module 'gmp' already loaded warning codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, warnings, gmp

I freshly installed CI 3.1.0 and once on several refreshes I recieve this warning

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning
Message: Module 'gmp' already loaded
Filename: Unknown
Line Number: 0
Backtrace:

Can you tell me what to do to fix this? Thank you in advance
P.S. I already have CI 3 and CI 2 installed on the server and they don't throw any warning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP remove/fix module not found or already loaded warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653926/php-remove-fix-module-not-found-or-already-loaded-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

go to your index.php file from your codeigniter root folder. Then set the value 0 in display error like the following codes:

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    break;
```

Comment: which wouldn't help much if the module is being loaded at the .ini level. changing error_reporting/display_errors at runtime does NOT help with startup errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the extension is already been loaded in the PHP.ini file.  Check the extensions that are being loaded and comment out the module in php.ini.

Hope that helps

Comment: it is a shared server. I don't have access to php.ini. But is strange that doesn't throw error on other CI installations

Comment: What does the change log say about ci3 to ci3.1. Does it have something about the gmp module.